# TensorFlow Probability: Different log probabilities for Sequential vs Named JointDistributions?

Tags: python, tensorflow-probability, probability-distribution

I'm fairly new to Bayesian estimation with TensorFlow. I was trying to set up a very simple regression of height on weight (using McElreath's [Howell data](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking/blob/master/data/Howell1.csv)) to familiarize myself with the machinery in TensorFlow Probability, but I am running into something I don't understand. I presumed that defining a model with `JointDistributionSequentialAutoBatched` would yield a model that was identical to one defined by `JointDistributionNamedAutoBatched`, but the latter would just yield some nice handles for getting at parameters.

```py
ht_wt: tfd.JointDistributionSequentialAutoBatched = tfd.JointDistributionSequentialAutoBatched([
    tfd.Normal(loc=tf.cast(0., dtype=tf.float64), scale=0.2),
    tfd.Normal(loc=tf.cast(0., dtype=tf.float64), scale=1.),
    tfd.Uniform(low=tf.cast(1., dtype=tf.float64), scale=10.),
    lambda beta0, beta1, sigma: tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(
        loc=beta0 + beta1 * weight,  # weight is a tf.Tensor of weights from Howell
        sigma=sigma
    ))
], name="Height vs Weight")

ht_wt_named: tfd.JointDistributionNamedAutoBatched = tfd.JointDistributionNamedAutoBatched([
    beta0=tfd.Normal(loc=tf.cast(0., dtype=tf.float64), scale=0.2),
    beta1=tfd.Normal(loc=tf.cast(0., dtype=tf.float64), scale=1.),
    sigma=tfd.Uniform(low=tf.cast(1., dtype=tf.float64), scale=10.),
    x=lambda beta0, beta1, sigma: tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(
        loc=beta0 + beta1 * weight,  # weight is a tf.Tensor of weights from Howell
        sigma=sigma
    ))
], name="Height vs Weight (Named)")
```

However, when I look at the distribution of logged probabilities across different parameter values, I get inconsistently different values.  For example...

```
beta0 = 1., beta1 = 1., sigma = 0.5
yields:
  Sequential = -19163.0633
  Named = -inf
```

```
beta0 = 1., beta1 = 1., sigma = 1.0
yields:
  Sequential = -5108.2755
  Named = -5108.2755
```

```
beta0 = 1., beta1 = 1., sigma = 1.5
yields:
  Sequential = -2616.9668
  Named = -2601.3418
```

I get different values when I vary the `beta` as well. Have I missed something about underlying differences between `Sequential` and `Named` `JointDistributions`?

Answer (score 0):

JDSequential "pops" distributions off a stack, so you need to reference them in reverse order. https://colab.research.google.com/gist/brianwa84/a47f4f43b1e58b9ac24ed34766478679/so69589226.ipynb